# How to disable xdebug during laravel installation via composer

Tags: php, laravel-5, xdebug

I'm installing laravel by using composer. But in command prompt screen, "You are running composer with xdebug enable. This has a major impact on runtime performance." this message is showing. I want to disable xdebug during laravel installation. Is there any problem, if xdebug is enabled in my system?

[[image: Picture of my error]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should temporarily disable xdebug in your console's `php.ini` before installation dependencies with Composer:

```
# Set xdebug autostart to false
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
xdebug.remote_enable=0

# Disable your profiller
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

And enable it when `composer install`/`composer update` finished.

Also, you can add `xdebug_disable()` function in your console PHP file if you don't want to enable/disable it in `php.ini` each time when work with Composer:

```
if (function_exists('xdebug_disable')) {
    xdebug_disable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel Homestead, I created a couple of aliases for turning on/off Xdebug quickly, and I use them before/after heavy composer commands, something like this:

```sh
$ xdebug_off # Disable Xdebug
  ...
$ composer heavy-load stuff
  ...
$ xdebug_on # Enable Xdebug
  ...
```

Once you are inside your box (after `vagrant ssh`), add these aliases to you `~/.profile` file:

```sh
# Xdebug aliases
alias xdebug_on='sudo phpenmod xdebug; sudo service php7.0-fpm restart;'
alias xdebug_off='sudo phpdismod xdebug; sudo service php7.0-fpm restart;'
```

If you do this a lot, you can use my shortcut, fire this command on your virtual machine:

```sh
curl -LsS https://git.io/vrc3y  >> ~/.profile; source ~/.profile
```